# Database for multiple types of users

Tags: mysql, database

I've been looking through different questions on here and I can't find something that exactly matches my situation.

I am designing a database for multiple types of users. I have one main User table which includes ID, Username, Password, PasswordSalt, AccountType (enum), and LastLoginDate. I need to have multiple types of accounts: Student, Parent, SchoolAdmin, SystemAdmin, Coordinator, and Teacher. I was originally thinking of having a separate table for each of these types of accounts, but I realized that SchoolAdmin, Coordinator, SystemAdmin, and Teacher all share the exact same data. These account types all have different permissions though. The Student and Parent accounts have extra information that they have to store.

I then thought about adding the information that the 4 identical tables share to the User table and then deleting those tables, but I came across another problem. I need to reference different types of accounts in other tables. For example, I had a foreign key for TeacherID in the Club table to show who the club sponsor is. If I add the information to the User table and get rid of those other tables, then how do I reference a specific account type in another table?

I have never designed a database like this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to make the type of account into a column? You could them do selects based on the types, determine permissions based on the types in code, etc.

Comment: @Velcromancer Thanks for the response. If I did that, then how would I handle referencing certain accounts in other tables? In the example I used above with the teacher and the club, only the teacher can be a sponsor. No other types of accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three main ways of implementing **inheritance** on database models. Please check the links below, and study which is the best one to solve your problem. Nothing better to start analyzing this types of situations to become a good architect.

[Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)

[Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)

[Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html)

Each of the different approaches have their pros and cons so choose wisely.

Comment: Which one would you suggest? I think I'm stuck between the concrete and class. I would like to avoid using single table @jandresrodriguez

Comment: @dabecks In order to end with a solution, you have to see pros and cons, ex. The Class Table requires a lot of joins between tables, The Concrete table makes difficult to manage ids. I repeat, the best for you is to see both and analyse them.

Comment: Because I dislike having to check multiple tables for the same data, I would probably use the single table inheritance method. If you can (and please bear in mind it will absolutely take a very long time, especially if you're new to PHP/MySQL) look up the PhpBB3 permission system. It's a very interesting set of permissions, with expandable sets for custom actions and plugins. Very diverse. I've modded it a few times for assorted projects. I'm sure Wordpress or another popular PHP/MySQL based software would be just as interesting.